# How do I get PowerShell 4 cmdlets such as Test-NetConnection to work on Windows 7?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-4.0

The situation.  On a Windows 7 SP1 machine, I have updated with Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu.  Furthermore, in PowerShell $PSVersionTable now reports ‘PSVersion 4.0’.

At present, my conclusion is that many PowerShell 4 cmdlets such Test-NetConnection, will only work on Windows 8.1. However, I was wondering if there was a work-around whereby I could import PowerShell 4 modules on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Your accepted answer is false.  You absolutely can have powershell 4 commands on Windows 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot. They rely on the underlying features of the newer OS (8.0 or 8.1) and cannot be ported back to Windows 7 . The alternative is to write your own functions / modules to replicate the new cmdlets using .NET framework methods.

For instance, the [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FileHash) cmdlet is a one-liner in PowerShell 4.0, but to replicate in 2.0 we have to use .NET.

PowerShell v4

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
```

PowerShell v2

```
$SHA1 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$file = [System.IO.File]::Open("C:\Windows\explorer.exe",[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($SHA1.ComputeHash($file)) -replace "-",""
$file.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am seeing more and more examples of PowerShell 4 features only working on Windows 8.1 and Server 2013.

Comment: **This answer is false.  You absolutely can have powershell 4 commands on Windows 7.**

Comment: The question was not 'Can you have PowerShell 4 on on Windows 7', but can you have Test-NetConnection on Windows 7. The key word is 'Net' Test-NetConnection, not Plain Test-Connection.

Comment: @Keltari Show me a windows 7 machine equipped with Net module cmdlets and I'll take back my downvotes.

Comment: bwerks is right. "New PowerShell functions and Modules are only added on current OS versions. PowerShell 3.0 is part of Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. PowerShell 4.0 is part of Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.
Older Versions of Windows will get the new Engine without the new Functions and Modules as they rely on newer OS features.
From <http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2013/10/superping-powershell-test-netconnection/>"

Comment: At least Test-NetConnection can be ported back to Windows 7. Just copy folders NetTCPIP, DnsClient, NetSecurity from supported Windows machine (win8.1, Win10 etc). Folder - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\. Then  `Import-Module -Name C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP -Verbose`

Comment: I think the answers below confirm that this answer is wrong. I was able to use @AntonKrouglov 's answer below to Import and use Test-NetConnection on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 11):

At least Test-NetConnection can be ported back to Windows 7. Just copy folders NetTCPIP, DnsClient, and NetSecurity from the supported Windows machine with the same PowerShell version (Windows 8.1, Windows 10, etc). Folder - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules. Then `Import-Module -Name C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP -Verbose`

Alternatively, you can import a module from a remote machine (say `win2012`):

```
$rsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName win2012
Import-Module NetTCPIP -PSSession $rsession
```

I have had the same problem on my Windows 7 x64 and both solutions worked for me as of PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: It even works across x86 and x64 versions. I am able to import the TCPIP module from Server 2012 R2 x64 to my x86 laptop.

Comment: While the import seems successful, there is a function within `Test-NetConnection` that refers to a function `Resolve-DnsName` that doesn't exist.  At least on my system anyways.

Comment: I'm unable to import these because of a manifest issue: 
"module cannot be imported because its manifest contains one or more members that are not valid..."

Comment: This is incorrect. I fooled myself into thinking this method works, however after a Import-Module using PSSession, the commands of the cmdlet/modules run on the remote machine instead of the local machine.

From MS docs
"When you import modules from another session, you can use the cmdlets in the current session. However, commands that use the cmdlets run in the remote session."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.1#example-13--import-a-module-from-a-remote-computer

Have verified this using couple of commands.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [Anton Krouglov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252824/how-do-i-get-powershell-4-cmdlets-such-as-test-netconnection-to-work-on-windows/43665239#43665239). PowerShell modules are cross-platform compatible. So a module copied from Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 can be imported to Windows 7 x86, and even if you are running as standard user without rights to copy them to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` you can copy it to any local folder, and run.

Assuming you copied the `NetTCPIP`, `DnsClient`, and `NetSecurity` modules from a Windows Server 2012 or higher machine, and save them to a folder you can import them using

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory .\psmodules | foreach { Import-Module -Name $_.FullName -Verbose}
Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel "Detailed"
```

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 7 (Version 6.1.7601) with PowerShell 5.0.10586.117.

To get rid of the Resolve-DnsName error, just import both NetTCPIP and DnsClient.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows Server 2008 R2/Windows 7 simply doesn't have the counters that the .NET methods use to implement get-netstuff.

A new PowerShell version can implement hash compare, etc. since this is not related to anything, just a piece of code. But *if* you want to use, for example, Get-NetTCPConnection there is nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

I see several responses which assert portability, and my testing confirms their assertions:

Import all of the required modules, either from file, or via a PSSession to a host which has the required modules.
The architecture of PowerShell Console (x86 or x64) you run will determine which module architecture you import.

For those who are:

- still unable to make this work
  AND
- do need a reliable TCP test, but may not need everything else provided by Test-NetConnection
  AND
- Need it all to work even on PowerShell v2.0

You may wish to try this.

```
# Create a TCP Client using .Net & attempt connection to target
$TCPClient = New-Object .net.sockets.tcpclient("[IP address or hostname]",[port])
# At the above point you may see familiar-looking Windows error messages in
# red text. (You may want to use "try/catch" if you intend to loop).
# Otherwise, check your new object's status to see if it worked
$TCPClient.Connected
# The response is either "True" or False"
# Now to avoid leaving idle connections, run:
$TCPClient.Close()
```

Naturally, it should be possible to create a loop which tests multiple connections, and outputs the results by selecting the properties of the $TCPClient.
My initial testing shows you would want to Select these properties

The address you tested

```
$TCPClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Address.IPAddressToString
```

The port you tested

```
$TCPClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Port
```

The result

```
$TCPClient.Connected
```

HIH

Answer (score -1):

While PowerShell 4.0 is available on Windows 7, as Knuckle-Dragger states certain features rely on newer operating system functionality. Unfortunately Test-NetConnection is not available in Windows 7 as [stated in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891.aspx).

[Test-**Connection**](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/7c54e3a1-8d8c-44ad-9056-ef0514c158d6.aspx), which is present, is basically ping. Test-**NetConnection** offers much more functionality, allowing a choice of things such as TCP ports, protocols, route tracing, and information levels.

There is a Send-Ping script available from the ScriptCenter in the TechNet gallery, but I think this is only really useful if you are stuck on PowerShell 3.0 for some reason.

Comment: Test-NetConnection [can be ported back Windows 7](http://srv-spb.ru/microsoft/windows/kak-proverit-port-cherez-powershell-na-windows-7.html)

Answer (score -11):

I can only assume you installed the wrong package.  Make sure you download the proper package from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx).

Below you will see in running Windows 7 Service Pack 1 with PowerShell 4 using [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) and [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FileHash):

[image]

Comment: This screenshot shows plain Test-Connection.  I asked about a different cmdlet called Test NetConnection.

Comment: hm...  well get-filehash is there

Comment: Screenshot issue aside, this answer is still wrong as `Test-NetConnection` (which was requested in the OP) is not available at all to Win7.