# PowerShell v5.1 test network port

Tags: powershell

I want to check to see if a port is open using PowerShell v5.1 on Windows 7.

On my Windows 10 laptop with PowerShell v5.1 I can use

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <IP> -Port <Port>
```

However, on my Windows 7 laptop the [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) cmdlet is not found. I have [`Test-Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) available, but that cmdlet doesn't allow me to specify a port.

Is there a way on Windows 7 with PowerShell 5.1 to test if a network port is open? How can I get the `Test-NetConnection` cmdlet back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit more mucking around but it can be done. [ScriptingGuy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/19/creating-a-port-scanner-with-windows-powershell/) has done it here. He also adds a ping sweep to it at the start.

Cut down version below. If you don't want to use variables, just put the IP and port in manually.

```
$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($ip, $port)

if($socket.Connected) {

    "$ip listening to port $port"
    $socket.Close()

}
```

[Test-NetConnection not available in Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252824/how-do-i-get-powershell-4-cmdlets-such-as-test-netconnection-to-work-on-windows)
has the answer to `Test-NetConnection` using Win7.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Thanks! I must have googled for an hour and couldn't find the link.  Very helpful thank you.

Comment: Glad we could help @indyodie

Answer (score 5):

Since `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` seems to throw an error when port is not open, I'd rather use a `try/catch` here:

```
$ip = "127.0.0.1"
$port = "80"

try {
    $socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($ip, $port)

    if($socket.Connected) {
        "success"
        $socket.Close()
    }
} catch {
    "error"
}
```

Comment: This is also very useful.  Thank you!

Comment: @indyodie you can upvote the answers you like, and choose one to accept (green checkmark near the votes).

Comment: I pressed the up arrow on both answers but the count didn't change.  Not sure I'm doing it right, but I'm trying again.  Thanks guys.